# MySQL SELECT SUM based on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have an table on `MySQL`

**tb_currencies**

```
currencyid | currency_name
CU0001     | IDR
CU0002     | SGD
CU0003     | USD
```

**tb_currency_converters**

```
currencyconverterid | currency_month | from_currencyid_fk | to_currencyid_fk | amount
CC0001              | 2018-03-01     | CU0001             | CU0002           | 0.00009
CC0002              | 2018-03-01     | CU0002             | CU0001           | 10425
CC0003              | 2018-03-01     | CU0003             | CU0002           | 1.31964
```

**tb_budgets**

```
budgetid       | budget_month | departmentid_fk | currencyid_fk
BU201803000001 | 2018-03-01   | DP0003          | CU0002
BU201803000002 | 2018-03-01   | DP0002          | CU0002
```

**tb_items**

```
itemid | item_name | currencyid_fk | price
IT0001 | Mouse     | CU0001        | 165000
IT0002 | Keyboard  | CU0002        | 20
IT0003 | TV LCD    | CU0003        | 350
```

**tb_pro_request**

```
requestid      | budgetid_fk    | itemid_fk | quantity
RQ201803000001 | BU201803000001 | IT0002    | 1
RQ201803000002 | BU201803000001 | IT0003    | 5
RQ201803000003 | BU201803000001 | IT0004    | 1
```

Example:

My `departmentid_fk` is: `DP0003`, means I have Budget with Currency `SGD`.

On **tb_pro_request**, there are 2 items transaction different currency(IDR & USD) with Budget Department Currency(SGD).

What I want is, that 2 items with different currency need to convert first to `SGD` (Due to my Department Budget is: SGD) then `SUM` it.

*Logic, if the currency is `SGD` then no need to convert, but if not `SGD` then convert it first using `tb_currency_converters` then `SUM` it.

Is it possible to do in directly to query?

My query code so far:

```
SELECT
    R.requestid,
    R.budgetid_fk,
    R.category,
    R.itemid_fk,
    SUM(R.quantity),
    R.request_date,
    R.investmentid_fk,
    R.remarks,
    R.approval_status,
    I.itemid,
    I.item_name,
    I.price,
    SUM(R.quantity) * I.price as total, 
    B.budgetid,
    B.budget_month
FROM
    tb_pro_request R,
    tb_items I,
    tb_budgets B
WHERE
    R.itemid_fk = I.itemid AND
    R.budgetid_fk = B.budgetid AND
    R.investmentid_fk = '' AND
    B.active = 'Y' AND
    (R.approval_status = 'P' OR R.approval_status = 'A') AND
    DATE_FORMAT(B.budget_month,'%Y-%m') = '2018-03' AND
    B.departmentid_fk = 'DP0003'
    GROUP BY I.currencyid_fk
```

You can see there are 3 items with different currency below.
What I want, convert to SGD for currency IDR, USD. then SUM it(to be 1 row)
[image]

Comment: Your question is hard to follow, because I can't see the expected output (a picture is worth a thousand words for SQL questions here).  You may want to also pare down your sample data, and only show the columns relevant directly to your query.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, please have a look on this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82da57/2 and I have updated my question picture description what I want

Comment: post the expected   result also in tabular (text) fomat .

Comment: Consider not storing 'CU000'

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Please have a look on Blag answer. It almost fix my issue. Now need to sum all the price after convert to SGD currency

Comment: You want one single result line with the total in SGD? That's it?

Comment: Yes correct, but before sum it, we need to convert the price to be SGD, because some of items is not in SGD currency

Comment: You `GROUP BY I.currencyid_fk` which means for every item currency you get one result row. This is not what you want. You want one result row for the budget's currency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I mess up a bit in your FK, but at least you have the spirit ;)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82da57/36)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
    R.budgetid_fk,
    SUM(R.quantity),
    SUM(R.quantity * I.price * COALESCE(CC.amount,1)) as total, 
    B.budgetid,
    B.budget_month
FROM tb_pro_request R 
INNER JOIN tb_items I 
  ON R.itemid_fk = I.itemid
INNER JOIN tb_budgets B 
  ON R.budgetid_fk = B.budgetid 
  AND B.active = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN tb_currency_converters CC 
  ON CC.from_currencyid_fk = I.currencyid_fk 
  AND CC.to_currencyid_fk = B.currencyid_fk
WHERE
    R.investmentid_fk = '' 
    AND (
      R.approval_status = 'P' 
      OR R.approval_status = 'A'
    ) 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(B.budget_month,'%Y-%m') = '2018-03' 
    AND B.departmentid_fk = 'DP0003'
GROUP BY R.budgetid_fk
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82da57/36/0)**:

```
|    budgetid_fk | SUM(R.quantity) |             total |       budgetid | budget_month |
|----------------|-----------------|-------------------|----------------|--------------|
| BU201803000001 |               7 | 575.2840143424692 | BU201803000001 |   2018-03-01 |
```

Comment: Hi @Blag, sorry for missing. For Total, formula need to get the currency amount on table tb_currency_converters. Example for requestid: `RQ201803000001`, price is IDR 149000 then on Total it should be convert to SGD Currency based on table tb_currency_converters. So 149000 * 0.00009

Comment: @HiDayurieDave better like that ? (I switched the to/from FK that was the wrong way)

Comment: OK I checked it and it's working, last question after We convert it I want to sum it for all 13.410000203293748 + 20 + 461.8740141391754 to be 1 row. Is it possible? Because I need to get the result for that price.

Comment: @HiDayurieDave answer updated, that's what you want ?

Comment: Cheers Sir ... Working perfect

Comment: @Blag: You should remove the second query from your answer, though. The query is invalid SQL. Requests and items are not functionally dependent on `tb_items.currencyid_fk`, so you must not select their unaggregated columns. (For instance in `SUM(R.quantity) * I.price * COALESCE(CC.amount,1) as total` you are using one item price arbitrarily chosen from all item prices matching the currency.)

Comment: Hi @Blag, Are your available on chat?

Comment: Need your advice regarding this case but different condition

Comment: @HiDayurieDave what your problem ? (maybe make a new question will be the best way to exchange information)

Comment: Hi... Blag. Please help a look on my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49232216/mysql-select-sum-based-on-another-table-another-case

Answer (score 1):

Your query is invalid SQL, because you are aggregating the data and still show unaggregated columns, such as the `requestid`. Which `requestid`? There can be several.

The following groups by budget currency. If `department_fk` plus `budget_month` are unique in the table `tb_budgets`, then we are selecting just a single one and can hence remove the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
select
  sum(i.price * r.quantity * coaleasce(cc.amount, 1)) as total,
  c.currency_name
from tb_budgets b 
join tb_pro_request r on  r.budgetid_fk = b.budgetid 
                      and r.approval_status in ('P','A')
                      and r.investmentid_fk = ''
join tb_items i on i.itemid = r.itemid_fk
join tb_currencies c on c.currencyid = b.currencyid_fk
left join tb_currency_converters cc on  cc.currency_month     = b.budget_month
                                    and cc.from_currencyid_fk = i.currencyid_fk
                                    and cc.to_currencyid_fk   = b.currencyid_fk
where b.departmentid_fk = 'DP0003'
and date_format(b.budget_month,'%Y-%m') = '2018-03'
and b.active = 'Y'
group by c.currency_name;
```

Comment: I got error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= itemid join c.currency c on c.currencyid = b.currencyid_fk left join tb_curren' at line 8

Comment: Oops, I started with `USING` clauses and switched to `ON` and made a mess. I've corrected the typo.

Comment: Still have an error: SELECT command denied to user 'user_9_82da57'@'100.96.8.14' for table 'currency'