# MySQL SELECT SUM based on another table (Another Case)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Continue my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104596/mysql-select-sum-based-on-another-table) before. But now I add some condition below:

As per working query code:

```
SELECT
R.budgetid_fk,
SUM(R.quantity),
SUM(R.quantity * I.price * COALESCE(CC.amount,1)) as total, 
B.budgetid,
B.budget_month
FROM tb_pro_request R 
INNER JOIN tb_items I 
  ON R.itemid_fk = I.itemid
INNER JOIN tb_budgets B 
  ON R.budgetid_fk = B.budgetid 
  AND B.active = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN tb_currency_converters CC 
  ON CC.from_currencyid_fk = I.currencyid_fk 
  AND CC.to_currencyid_fk = B.currencyid_fk
WHERE
    R.investmentid_fk = '' 
    AND (
      R.approval_status = 'P' 
      OR R.approval_status = 'A'
    ) 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(B.budget_month,'%Y-%m') = '2018-03' 
    AND B.departmentid_fk = 'DP0002'
GROUP BY R.budgetid_fk;
```

On that code, It will get the total SUM of price from some column.

```
requestid      | budgetid_fk    | category  | itemid_fk | quantity | currencyid_fk | price | discount | userid_fk
RQ201803000001 | BU201803000002 | Item      | IT0001    |          |       |
RQ201803000002 | BU201803000002 | Project   |           | 20       | CU0002 | 750 | 10 | US0004
```

Now I need to add extra code to calculate Category Project(**RQ201803000002**)

price accumulate with

```
SUM(R.quantity * I.price * COALESCE(CC.amount,1)) as total
```

Logic:

```
(quantity * (price * currency)) - discount as total2

*need to convert the currency first
*get department from userid_fk
```

Then accumulate it

```
total + total2
```

You can see the sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3933e4/1)

Comment: what the unit of discount ? (do we need to change currency too ?)

Comment: What your request so far? Explain exactly how to get the discount and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want this (apart if the `discount` come form another table ?):

```
SUM(R.quantity * (I.price - discount) * COALESCE(CC.amount,1)) as total
```

Comment: Please have a look on table `tb_pro_request` the price is not getting from tb_items, but from same table `tb_pro_request`